# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined in IE and Chrome Firefox is fine

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a strange error I don't understand. In Firefox 11 everything is allright. Chrome and IE 9 are making trouble and give the same errors for this line:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

```
 curr_url_id=window.content.document.location.href;
```

Any help with that?

Comment: Documentation for [`window.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content). Does it match your expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just `window.location.href`.

If you're actually trying to access an iframe's location, try `iframe.contentWindow.location.href`